# Perform soap request via https with self-signed certificate by cURL

Tags: php, soap, curl, https

I'm trying to perform soap request to web-service written on C# via https. Server uses self-signed certificate.

After many failed attempts with usage of [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/SoapClient) I decided to use pure [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) to perfrom request.

My code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$url      = 'https://ip:8443/ServiceName';
$admin    = 'login';
$password = 'haShedPassw0rdHere';

$post     =
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        // Soap service params xml
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$headers = array(             
    'Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"',
    'Accept: text/xml', 
    'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
    'Pragma: no-cache', 
    'SOAPAction: https://ip:8443/ServiceName',
    'Content-length: ' . strlen($post),
);

$curl = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $admin . ':' . $password,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => '',
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

var_dump($response = curl_exec($curl));
?>
```

Response:

```
string(370) "
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                a:InvalidSecurity
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="ru-RU">
                Ошибка при проверке безопасности сообщения.
            </faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>"
```

Where:

> Ошибка при проверке безопасности сообщения.

Means something like:

> Communication security check error.

What have I tried:

1. [POST request with a self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690173/post-request-with-a-self-signed-certificate)
2. [How to consume a WCF Web Service that uses custom username validation with a PHP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652227/how-to-consume-a-wcf-web-service-that-uses-custom-username-validation-with-a-php)
3. [Php SoapClient stream_context option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909232/php-soapclient-stream-context-option)
4. [SOAP authentication with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934639/soap-authentication-with-php)
5. [How can I send SOAP XML via Curl and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006977/how-can-i-send-soap-xml-via-curl-and-php)

And more of them.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

Regards.

**P.S.:** Tested with `PHP 5.3`, `PHP 5.4.14`, `PHP 5.5.1`. Results are same.

---

**UPDv1:**

C# Source, provided by service support team:

```
private void Button_SetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eLeed.WebServiceClient client =
        new eLeed.WebServiceClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "login";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "haShedPassw0rdHere";
    Stream input = null;
    input = GetQuery("ServiceMethod", TextBox_Command.Text);
    XmlDocument response = new XmlDocument();
    response.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    response.Load(client.SetDataContractor(input));
    ExeResponse(response);
    input.Close();
    client.Close();
}
```

Well, this button is actually working. But how perform something like that in php with cURL ? Especially, how to pass those two lines:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "login";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "haShedPassw0rdHere";
```

Therefore, shouldn't it return message like "invalid credentials" or something?

Comment: can you translate the Russian error message

Comment: @DevZer0 Sorry. Just noticed.

Comment: Does the soap api dictate some form of security mechanism, like some sort of key hash against the body in the header? if your familiar with Amazon `MWS` it requires a signature to be created using a privateKey using all the payload of the body to be passed in as part of the header

Comment: @DevZer0 Nope. Nothing like that.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea what `eLeed`-does

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin it is a namespace of the app in C#.

Comment: Then I still don't know about the  WebServiceClient` Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesnt seem to be on the client side but on the server side. The server says that some security check failed. If it was a client error, you would get nothing but an error by cURL. You get an XML answer.

You should look at the server side.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, server and web-service is not under my control. But I'm looking forward to contact support. As they were telling before, they "don't know what is wrong with it".

Comment: From the new data it seems like it is not the server but your script. You don't send the necessary information to the server. It needs some kind auf authentication. It is impossible to tell how the authentication works with the information provided.

Comment: Well, that's all info that support provided. I do not know complete auth algorithm too. But, as they (and you) mentioned, that is probably their problem.